# PHP rand password based on specific time?

Tags: php, mysql, security, date, passwords

I've a localhost php mysql point of sale (windows) and I have found this code which is about generating `rand` numbers based on specified time (every min) :
Here is the code :

```
<?php
class Random {

    // random seed
    private static $RSeed = 0;

    //set seed
    public static function seed($s = 0) {
        self::$RSeed = abs(intval($s)) % 9999999 + 1;
        self::num();
    }


    // generate random number
    public static function num($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        if (self::$RSeed == 0) self::seed(mt_rand());
        self::$RSeed = (self::$RSeed * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$RSeed % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }

}


// set seed
Random::seed(check_time());

// echo 10 numbers between 1 and 100
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo Random::num(1, 100) . '<br />';
}


function check_time(){
echo "Your Time is = ".date('h:i:s')."<br />";
if (date('i')) {
   return date('i');
}
}

?>
```

Now this works perfectly, but this is not what i really need. I am looking for an idea to use the `rand` output numbers to access my admin area web page. How is it possible to do it ? Like before a week ago i got a new HSBC security card which generates random numbers and sync with their servers. Is it really hard to do it like this with PHP and Mysql ?

As a conclusion to clarify what i want, I need a random numbers generated every min and should be sync with mysql db - maybe -? in order to access the admin area.

I am looking for the first step to get along with this idea, Sorry I'm not familiar with PHP security !

Thank You.

Comment: Storing random numbers etc.? That's not a good approach. You want to implement this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm - as a starting point you could have a look at the google authenticator sourcecode: http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/

Comment: @ThiefMaster Will read about that, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers are not "random", if they were there'd be no way two parties could know the same number at the same time. Those authenticator tokens are OTP (One-Time Password) devices. Google has created a great open-source implementation of an OTP service: [Google Authenticator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator). There are implementations for the protocol available in many languages.

The system depends on two parties exchanging a *shared secret* once. When setting this up, the server generates a secret and your phone or other device gets this secret; often by scanning a QR code. Both machines now generate a seemingly unpredictable number based on that initial secret and the current time of day.

For another nice, easy-to-add implementation of this see http://authy.com.